# jQuery: Scrolling Dynamically Generated List Items

Tags: jquery, pagination, scroll, cycle

I am trying to incorporate Valums's scroll script (http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/) to a dynamically created pagination of the Cycle plugin, http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager2.html. Basically I am trying to get the dynamic pagination (1, 2, 3...) to scroll on mousemove.

So, I have the original Cycle demo code:

$('#slideshow').before('').cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    pager:  '#nav',

```
// callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
}
```

});

And then I am trying to apply:

$(function(){
    //Get our elements for faster access and set overlay width
    var div = $('div#nav'),
                 ul = $('ul#nav'),
                 // unordered list's left margin
                 ulPadding = 15;

```
//Get menu width
var divWidth = div.width();

//Remove scrollbars
div.css({overflow: 'hidden'});

//Find last image container
var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');

//When user move mouse over menu
div.mousemove(function(e){

  //As images are loaded ul width increases,
  //so we recalculate it each time
  var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;

  var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;
  div.scrollLeft(left);
});
```

});

The problem is that:

var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');

can not find the last element because all elements are dynamically created. Any ideas how the scripts could be bounded so the elements within #nav are scrollable on mousemove?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try your code out, but jQuery should find your dynamically created elements no matter what.

```
<div>
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
    <span>four</span>
  </div>

<script>
    $("div span:last-child")
        .css({color:"red", fontSize:"80%"})
        .hover(function () {
              $(this).addClass("someclass");
            }, function () {
              $(this).removeClass("someclass");
            });

</script>
```

Try to recreat this list dynamically.

P.S.
You are missing the 'alt' attribute in your images.

Comment: In your example 

<div>
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
    <span>three</span>
    <span>four</span>
  </div>

is not dynamically generated via jQuery. My issue is that 
var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');
does not actually see the dynamically generated pagination in the cycle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had to use `.live()` as shown below:

```
div.live('mousemove', function(e) {
        var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');
        var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;
        var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;
        div.scrollLeft(left);
    });
```